# Changing either an actor or an actress

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, movies

**About**

> After the completion of this table, each row will have an actor and an actress who acted together in a movie directed by the director in that row.

[image]

---

**Rule**

> While moving from the first row to the last row, in each row, either the actor or the actress must have been changed from the previous row. If the actor is changed, then the actress remains unchanged and vice versa.

---

**Task**

> ***Complete the table and find out the director X.***

---

**Textual form of the image**

| Actor | Actress | Director |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | X |
|  | Helena Bonham Carter | Tim Burton |
|  |  | David Koepp |
|  |  | X |
| Ethan Hawke |  | Alfonso Cuarón |
|  |  | Don Roos |
|  |  | X |

Comment: Does it have to alternate between the actor and actress changing, or can e.g. the same actress appear for 3 in a row (but with different actors)?

Comment: Your example is valid. i.e., for example, the same actress can appear 3 in a row (but with different actors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The director X is

> David Fincher

The completed table (with the movie added):

| Actor | Actress | Director | Movie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Edward Norton | Helena Bonham Carter | *David Fincher* | Fight Club (1999) |
| Johnny Depp | **Helena Bonham Carter** | **Tim Burton** | Charlie and the Chocolate Factory (2005) and 4 more |
| Johnny Depp | Gwyneth Paltrow | **David Koepp** | Mortdecai (2015) |
| Brad Pitt | Gwyneth Paltrow | *David Fincher* | Se7en (1995) |
| **Ethan Hawke** | Gwyneth Paltrow | **Alfonso Cuarón** | Great Expectations (1998) |
| Ben Affleck | Gwyneth Paltrow | **Don Roos** | Bounce (2000) |
| Ben Affleck | Rosamund Pike | *David Fincher* | Gone Girl (2014) |